# Push notification if web server goes down

Tags: ios, macos, bash, ubuntu, push

Is it possible to send a push notification to my Mac and my Android devices if, for example, my WebServer(s) go down, or if a particular script is running?

Comment: I suggest using some commercial offering, like Pingdom.com. For details and list of alternatives, see: https://starthq.com/apps/pingdom

Comment: Are you suggesting that he rephrase his question? Replace "if for example my webserver(s) ..." with "if for example Pingdom's web server(s) ...".

Comment: No i think he is suggesting to use pingdoms service rather than writing a script for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to employ CURL utility for such task: http://curl.haxx.se

Script it for periodical access to the index of your site (schedulers like CRON, Quartz etc), then parse the response.

If web-site is alive, CURL will receive something like "HTTP 1.1 200 OK" header, otherwise you can start your custom logic (script to send SMS, email, puch notification - whatever suits you) and report then what CURL actually receives (404, 500, timeout etc).

Comment: This doesnt help send a push notification it jsut tells me how to check if the webserver is alive? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know about push notifications or android, if you're on 10.8 [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel) should give you some help for using the built-in notification center; I'm not on 10.6.8 so I haven't tested.

If you want to use the older, free version of [growl](http://growl.info/downloads) you can use the add-on `growlnotify` utility:

`growlnotify -t Terminal -m "The System... Is Down." && tput bel`

I hear rumors that in 10.7 that's more fun.